# How to count firebase database in python using pyrebase?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

How can we do count() for firebase database in python ?

as for example ..

count = db.child("users").get().count()

Comment: Realtime Database doesn't have a simple count operation.  You have to download the entire contents of the node and count the children on the client, or maintain a count value somewhere else in your database when the data changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `len` function for this as:

`len(db.child('users').get().val())`

Comment: @YusufMohdSuhair if you think its the right answer mark it as currect and upvote please :)

Comment: This is **not** a count operation.  This is downloading the entire contents of the database at the "users" location, then counting the number of children on the client.  If you do this, it could cost a lot of time and money.  Be aware of that before you use this code.

Comment: hmmm do you have any idea for the best way for counting it ?